# Trouble with MPI_Allgather

Tags: mpi

I trying to implement matrix matrix multiplication in MPI using rowwise and columnwise broadcast with `MPI_Allgather`. Although commented out code part works well, other one(below it) does not work(i.e. gives signal -5 and mpi process is killed). Any help please?
    Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define N 4  // NxN is origininal(big) matrices size to multiply


int SqrtRoot(int a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1: return 1 ;

        case 4: return 2;   

        case 9: return 3;

        case 16: return 4;

        default: return -1;
    }
}

int main( argc, argv )
int  argc;
char **argv;
{  
    int myID, p;
    double t1,t2;
    double *RowwiseA, *ColWiseB; // 1D array of size N*N/sqrt(p) to hold the 2D data of 
                                 // processors own datatogether with data of its rowwise neighbours
    double* MyResult; // my result of size of nxn(n = N/p) is also stored 1D

    int mydatastartindex;

    int i,j,n;


    MPI_Comm MyRowPartners, MyColPartners;

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myID );

    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myID/SqrtRoot(p), myID,&MyRowPartners);
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myID%SqrtRoot(p), myID,&MyColPartners);
    int DataPerProcess = N*N/(p);

    RowwiseA = (double*) malloc(N*N/SqrtRoot(p) * sizeof(double));
    ColWiseB = (double*) malloc(N*N/SqrtRoot(p) * sizeof(double));
    MyResult = (double*) malloc(N*N/p * sizeof(double));

    mydatastartindex = myID * DataPerProcess;

    n = SqrtRoot(N*N/p); // one deimension of local square matrix of nxn

    // initialize my dat
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)  {
        RowwiseA [mydatastartindex + i*n + j] = (i + j) * (myID + 1);
        ColWiseB [mydatastartindex + i*n + j] = (i - j) * (myID + 1);
        }
    }   

    // ------------ THIS ONE WORKS ------------------
    //double* sum = (double*)malloc(4*sizeof(double));
    //
    //double mydata = myID*1.0f;

    //MPI_Allgather(
    //              &mydata ,           
    //              1,              
    //              MPI_DOUBLE,     
    //              sum,        
    //              1,             
    //              MPI_DOUBLE,     
    //              MyRowPartners  
    //          );
    //  
    //--------------------------------------------------        

    //--------THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK----------------------
    MPI_Allgather(
                    &RowwiseA[mydatastartindex],            
                    DataPerProcess,                 
                    MPI_DOUBLE,     
                    RowwiseA ,      
                    DataPerProcess,            
                    MPI_DOUBLE,     
                    MyRowPartners  
                );
    //-----------------------------------------------------


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. I should use new rank inside MyRowPartners instead of myID
in MPI_ALLgather and also in matrix indexes. Thanks though..

Comment: When you answer your own question on StackOverflow, you can still mark your answer as correct after a couple of days. I'd encourage you to do that, though this question might get closed anyway since the answer is not likely to help others. This problem was very specific to your situation.